# What is the probability that the center of the sphere is contained by any one of the faces of a tetrahedron whose vertices lie on the sphere?

Tags: probability

Four arbitrarily chosen points on a sphere form a tetrahedron.  What is the probability that the center of the sphere is contained by any one of the faces of the tetrahedron?

This a variation of the 6th problem of Putnam 1992.

I think it is $\frac{1}{8}$ multiplied by the ratio of the sum of the areas of the faces of regular tetrahedron to its volume.I don't know if that is true...

Comment: I feel that the answer should be zero. But I am not sure.

Comment: @KingTut: You can be almost sure.  It cannot be more than the probability that three of the vertices lie on a great circle, and that is $0$

Comment: It cant be $0$ as there are cases.